# Simply print the string backwards

Tags: c++, performance, strings

This code is **very, very** simple, but I was wondering how it could be improved:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    for(int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++){
        std::cout << input[input.length() - i];
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This code takes a string `input`, and prints it backwards. For example:

```
This will be printed backwards.
```

Becomes:

```
.sdrawkcab detnirp eb lliw sihT
```

Given the simplicity of this code, is there a way to optimize it? I understand that since it is very short, it will run fast no matter what. However, I hate inefficiencies in code, and I want to help improve the way that I write code.

This is related to, but not copied directly from, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13185768). (I only found this SO answer after writing the code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple improvement would be to restructure the `for()` loop:

```
for(int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    std::cout << input[i];
}
```

A simple decrement operation might lead to more efficient machine code than calculating `input.length() - i` in every iteration.

---

Another improvement would be to use a more c++-ish way. But that means to change the string itself:

```
 std::getline(std::cin,input);
 std::reverse(std::begin(input),std::end(input));
 std::cout << input << '\n';
```

---

Or using the reverse iterators in the loop:

```
 for(auto it = input.rbegin(); it != input.rend(); ++it) {
      std::cout << *it;
 }
```

---

As I've mentioned in my [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152615/simply-print-the-string-backwards/152616#comment288226_152616), the most generic (and c++stylish) way to achieve that is to write your own adapter to achieve iterating a sequence in the reverse order. So I'm citing that solution here:

> ```
>  // -------------------------------------------------------------------
>  // --- Reversed iterable
>  using namespace std; // for rbegin() and rend()
>
>  template <typename T>
>  struct reversion_wrapper { T& iterable; };
>
>  template <typename T>
>  auto begin (reversion_wrapper<T> w) { return rbegin(w.iterable); }
>
>  template <typename T>
>  auto end (reversion_wrapper<T> w) { return rend(w.iterable); }
>
>  template <typename T>
>  reversion_wrapper<T> reverse (T&& iterable) { return { iterable }; }
> ```

Above taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28139075/1413395).

Comment: Ah yes, this is what was suggested in the SO answer. Does restructuring it just improve the *visual aspect* of reading the code, or is it a common practice, or does it improve how it runs?

Comment: @Idempotence I'd say both.

Comment: @Idempotence You might also be interested in this [SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542591/c11-reverse-range-based-for-loop)

Comment: It *does* make a difference in the generated machine code, @Idempotence, at least on x86. Either of the ways πάντα ῥεῖ suggested are going to result in more efficient machine code being generated, and thus will theoretically be faster. (This won't be benchmarkable in practice, though, because the runtime will be dwarfed by the call to `std::cout`.) Looking at Clang's output, both of these alternatives result in comparable machine code, but the first one tends to result in *slightly* more efficient code inside the inner loop, whereas I'd say the iterator-based solution is more readable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks that SO Q&A was very helpful. I also appreciate you updating your question, I had no idea that `std::reverse`, `.rbegin()`, and `.rend()` were even things!

Comment: @Idempotence De nada. You probably meant I've _updated my answer_. I rarely write them in one go here.

Answer (score 4):

another way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::copy(input.rbegin(), input.rend(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));

    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

If I were going to do this often, I'd be tempted to make a little library extension:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

namespace notstd {
    template<class Iter>
    struct reverser
    {
        using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;

        template<class Ch, class Traits>
        std::basic_ostream<Ch, Traits>& 
        operator ()(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Traits>& os) const
        {
            std::copy(first, last, 
                      std::ostream_iterator<value_type, Ch, Traits>(os));
            return os;
        }

        Iter first, last;

        template<class Ch, class Traits>
        friend std::basic_ostream<Ch, Traits>& 
        operator <<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Traits>& os, reverser eng)
        {
            return eng(os);
        }
    };

    template<class Iter>
    auto make_reverser(Iter first, Iter last)
    {
        return reverser<Iter> {first, last};
    }

    template<class Iter,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>, char>::value>* = nullptr
    >
    auto to_string(const reverser<Iter>& eng)
    {
        return std::string(eng.first, eng.last);
    }

    template<class Iter,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>, wchar_t>::value>* = nullptr
    >
    auto to_string(const reverser<Iter>& eng)
    {
        return std::wstring(eng.first, eng.last);
    }

    template<class Range>
    auto reversed(Range&& range)
    {
        return make_reverser(std::rbegin(range), std::rend(range));
    }

    template<class Elem, std::size_t N,
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same<char, std::remove_cv_t<Elem>>::value or
            std::is_same<wchar_t, std::remove_cv_t<Elem>>::value
        > * = nullptr
    >
    auto reversed(Elem (& range)[N])
    {
        static_assert(N > 0, "");
        return make_reverser(std::rbegin(range) + 1,
                             std::rend(range));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string input = argv[0];
//    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    std::cout << notstd::reversed(input) << '\n';
    std::cout << notstd::reversed("Hello") << std::endl;
    std::wcout << notstd::reversed(L"World") << std::endl;

    std::cout << to_string(notstd::reversed("baloney")) << std::endl;
    std::wcout << to_string(notstd::reversed(L"wide baloney")) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
don/gubed-dliub-ekamc/tcejorp/yalp/segdohr/sresU/
olleH
dlroW
yenolab
yenolab ediw
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Comment: @coderodde Well, I think it mostly resembles that SO answer I have linked in my comment. Isn't that plagiarism to some degree? I refrained to extend my answer citing that generic code. But yes, it's probably the best way to do that using c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I honestly have no idea, I didn't read the comment or the SO answer. I don't know whether it's fair to call proper use of the standard library, "plagiarism" :-) Certainly the concepts I have used here are not new (to you or me), but they may be new to other readers of this site. I hope I have covered enough concepts in this answer to provoke the OP to think more deeply about idiomatic and expressive code, plus highlight the options available in the standard library.

Comment: @Richard I didn't want to say your answer is inherently bad, don't let me be misunderstood ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no offence taken I assure you.  I think we all contribute because we like to share knowledge and be appreciated for it. If we're inadvertently cluttering the site by repeating the same points, it's right to highlight that so we can undo the damage.

Comment: @Richard Well, the `std::copy()` proposal merely resembles what `std::reverse` already does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::reverse` is destructive. my `reversed` function is not. It returns an object which reverse-copies the characters into the output stream. The `to_string` call (which makes a reversed copy) is there for exposition.

Comment: @Richard Well, you're right. I realized that just after I wrote that.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a string from a pair of iterators, so it seems to me that the method that's probably simplest is something on this order:

```
std::string my_string = "Hello, World!";

std::cout << std::string(my_string.rbegin(), my_string.rend()) << '\n';
```

#### Return from main

I'd also eliminate the `return 0;` from `main`. If you don't specify otherwise, `main` returns `0` by default.

#### #include what you use

Your code uses `std::string`, so it should `#include <string>` to make it available.

Answer (score 2):

To print any container that supports bidirectional iterators, which include not only plain ascii strings but also unicode strings, vectors, dequeues ...

```
// somecode.h
#include <utility>

template<typename Cont>
void print_bidir_cont(Cont& cont) noexcept(noexcept(std::cout))
{
    auto lside{ c.rbegin() };
    auto rside{ c.rend() };
    while( lside < rside) std::cout << *lside++;
}
```

then use it like:

```
// main.cpp
#include "somecode.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the string to revert: ";
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    print_bidir_cont(s);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // ...

    std::vector<double> v{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    std::cout << "Reverting a vector too:";
    print_bidir_cont(v);

    std::cout << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

...yet I still ask myself why do some have their strings stored backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple reverse iterator is probably the simplest and most effective way of improving your code:

```
std::string my_string = "Hello World!";

for(auto IT = my_string.rbegin(); IT != my_string.rend(); IT++)
{
  std::cout<<*IT<<std::endl;
}
```

I would avoid ostreams  as 1) over complicates a very simple operation and 2) `std::cout` fits you problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XOR swap algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string revStr(string str)
{
    int end= str.length() - 1;
    int start = 0;

    while(start < end)
    {
        str[start] ^= str[end];
        str[end]   ^= str[start];
        str[start] ^= str[end];

        ++start;
        --end;
    }

    return str;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << revStr("Test");

    return 0;
}
```